# ruby openssl smime encryption

Tags: ruby, openssl, smime

I am looking for ruby code to mimic below openssl smime encryption. I looked up other related topics but mostly were around signing. In snippet below cert.pem is a PEM-encoded X.509 certificate containing the PEM public key. token.txt file is the file to be encrypted.

`openssl smime -encrypt -out encrypted.p7m -in token.txt cert.pem`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it.

```
    token_plain_text = File.read("/path/to/token.txt")
    cert = X509::Certificate.new("/path/to/cert.pem")
    encrypted_object = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([cert], token_plain_text)
```

Got the encrypted string by outputting above object to string.

```
    encrypted_str = encrypted_object.to_str
```